# Raising a square array to the power of N in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm writing a C program to compute a square array raised to the power of N.

I'd like to write these in separate functions to keep it clean. I have a function

```
arrMult(int M, int R[M][M], int X[M][M], int out[M][M])
```

which essentially does `out = R*X`. To raise it to some Nth power, I wrote this function:

```
int arrNthPow(int M, int N, int R[M][M], int out[M][M])
{
    // Initialize
    arrPrint(M, M, out);
    arrMult(M, R, R, out);
    for (int i = 1; i < N - 1; i++){
        arrPrint(M, M, out);
        arrMult(M, R, out, out);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, I realise that this doesn't give me the result I expect. Instead, if I do

```
arrMult(M, R, R, out1);
arrMult(M, out1, R, out2);
arrMult(M, out2, R, out3);
```

`out3` gets me the answer I'm looking for. I'm assuming that I have to somehow use pointers to copy the value of each array output after `arrMult` before using `arrMult` again for the next iteration but I'm not sure how.

I'm not very familiar with pointers however and have no clue on how to write this without copying the values to a `temp` variable and using additional for loops.

Comment: Try `arrMult(M, out, R, out);` inside the `for` loop

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] Your code would not compile.

Comment: What you show seems like you are multiplying `R` by itself 3-times. If so, your `arrMult(M, R, R, out1);, arrMult(M, out1, R, out2);  arrMult(M, out2, R, out3);` would be correct.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin that is correct. However, I'd like to do this `N` times (write a function to do it for me instead of typing it out 3 times for `R^4`).

Comment: @Haris I have tried that but it didn't give me the result I wanted. Raising `R` to the power of 4 gives me `3244956, 3988584, 4732212` for the first three elements of the first row of the array, which is incorrect (and incredibly huge).

Comment: @wickedk: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- there is an extra argument in `arrMult(int M, int M, int R[M][M], int X[M][M], int out[M][M])`
- the `out` matrix should be set to the unity matrix if `N == 0`.
- the `out` matrix should receive a copy of `R` if `N == 1`.
- otherwise `out` starts at `R`<sup>2</sup>, but it is unlikely you can pass the same matrix as input and output to `arrMult`. You should use a temporary matrix to store the result and copy it to `out` either inside `arrMult` or after each matrix multiplication.
- there is a more efficient algorithm to compute powers in **log N** steps rather than **N** steps as posted: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring

Here is a simple implementation:

```
void arrIdentity(int M, int out[M][M]) {
    /* initialize array to identity matrix. */
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            out[i][j] = (i == j);
        }
    }
}    

void arrCopy(int M, const int mat[M][M], int out[M][M]) {
    /* copy a matrix. */
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            out[i][j] = mat[i][j];
        }
    }
}    

void arrMult(int M, const int R[M][M], const int X[M][M], int out[M][M]) {
    /* compute matrix multiplication: out = R * X. */
    int temp[M][M];

    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < M; k++) {
                sum += R[i][k] * X[k][j];
            }
            temp[i][j] = sum;
        }
        arrCopy(M, temp, out);
    }
}

int arrNthPow(int M, int N, const int R[M][M], int out[M][M]) {
    /* Naive matrix exponentiation */
    if (N < 0)
        return -1;
    if (N == 0) {
        arrIdentity(M, out);
        return 0;
    } else {
        arrCopy(M, R, out);
        for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
            arrMult(M, R, out, out);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is a more efficient alternative using the method explained in the Wikipedia article:

```
int arrNthPow2(int M, int N, const int R[M][M], int out[M][M]) {
    /* Matrix exponentiation by squaring */
    int X[M][M];

    if (N < 0)
        return -1;
    if (N == 0) {
        arrIdentity(M, out);
        return 0;
    }
    if (N == 1) {
        arrCopy(M, R, out);
        return 0;
    }
    if (N == 2) {
        arrMult(M, R, R, out);
        return 0;
    }
    arrIdentity(M, out);
    arrCopy(M, R, X);
    while (N > 1) {
        if (N & 1)
            arrMult(M, X, out, out);
        arrMult(M, X, X, X);
        N >>= 1;
    }
    arrMult(M, X, out, out);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And the `out` matrix *is* initialized by the virtue of being the result matrix of R². However, 3rd point is where the error is...